# Query value inside of another query

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I have these two queries

```
 $q = "INSERT INTO pages (title, subtitle, link_title, content, posted) VALUES ('$t', '$st', '$lt', '$c', UTC_TIMESTAMP())";
$pq = "SELECT page_id FROM pages WHERE posted = {$q['posted']}";
```

I need to get the page_id from pages where the the UTC timestamp equals the posted value in the first query. How is this possible? Basically I need to call the array query value from the first one into the second.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1. Make sure you absolutely have to insert the data before working with it in PHP. Otherwise, it might make sense to work with the data and insert afterwards.
2. Assuming you passed the test in #1, Run `mysql_query($q);`
3. Check the response for errors and handle them if there are any
4. If the query succeeded, get the ID of the inserted row with `mysql_insert_id();`
5. Run `mysql_query($pq)`, using the value of the inserted ID to retrieve the row you just inserted.

Comment: Thats pretty much what I needed however, I just tried it and mysql_insert_id(); echoed out as 0


`$q = "INSERT INTO pages (title, subtitle, link_title, content, posted) VALUES ('$t', '$st', '$lt', '$c', UTC_TIMESTAMP())";`
`$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the Query.`
`if ($r) { //If it ran OK`
`$myid = mysql_insert_id();`
`echo $myid;`
@ZachRattner

Comment: If mysql_insert_id() gave you 0, then you have an error with the first query. What does mysql_error() give you?

Comment: I didn't get any errors, I checked my tables too, the insert worked fine... :(

Comment: Are you passing a connection parameter to mysql_insert_id?

Comment: I tried
`$myid = mysql_insert_id($dbc, $q);` and I get the error
mysql_insert_id() expects at most 1 parameter, 2 given

and i tried
`$myid = mysql_insert_id($q);`
i get the error mysql_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: It should be `$myid = mysql_insert_id($dbc);` See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Now i getmysql_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given O_O

Comment: Did you create `$dbc` with `mysql_connect`? I might have to see your code.

Comment: Yes sir, 
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'sandbox');


$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

Comment: You created the connection with `mysqli_connect`, not `mysql_connect`. You have to be consistent and use `mysqli_insert_id`: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Haha, no problem. When you have a minute, take some time to look over why that happened. The mysqli is an improvement (hence the "i") over the default mysql functions. It's always good to know why your code works, not just that it does work.

Comment: For sure, sometimes I just need a human to explain it to me in regular language, even reading documentation sometimes confuses me. >_< Appreciate your help and patience!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting MySQL generate the timestamp, can you generate it from PHP and use that in both functions?

Alternatively, instead of running the second query, why not just use the mysql_insert_id to get the id of the last query you ran - this is a lot more foolproof and doesn't require a second query.

Comment: Using timestamp to identify rows can be problematic.  Some datatypes are not millisecond accurate, for instance, and can cause rounding issues when querying by that timestamp.  I second niggle's approach of using mysql_insert_id, but this will only work for single inserts.  If you need to insert more, you need to come up with a more unique set of values to query by, or avoid use of the automated ID's altogether, instead generating ID's in your code using some algorithm or a pseudo sequence using a sequence number control table.